# Place PHP variables inside div

Tags: php, string, variables, echo

This may be a simple question but I don't quite know how to search for it. I am running a loop that pulls a bunch of wordpress posts. In that loop, I want to create a div that displays the variables (a div for each post), with some text formatting.

Normally this would be simple for me, but I'm using a different type of variable and I don't quite know how to handle it, partially because I just don't know what the proper name of that variable is.

Here's my code:

```
echo $postInfo['article_title'];
echo "<br>";
echo $postInfo['article_content'];
echo "<br><br>";
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
echo "<div class="entry"><h1>$postInfo['article_title']</h1>
      <p>$postInfo['article_content']</p>
      </div>";
```

I realize that is incorrect, just looking for someone to show me the way! I know things get dicey with multiple quotation marks. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need concatenation of variable with html Try

```
echo "<div class='entry'><h1>".$postInfo['article_title']."</h1>
      <p>".$postInfo['article_content']."</p>
      </div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to concat the values

```
echo "<div class='entry'><h1>".$postInfo['article_title']."</h1>
      <p>".$postInfo['article_content']."</p>
      </div>";
```

Comment: Is it differ from my answer?

Comment: that is the answer how to different in answer in concat the values @RakeshSharma

Answer (score 1):

You can do that too :

```
<div class="entry">
<h1><?=$postInfo['article_title']?></h1>
<p><?=$postInfo['article_content']?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
echo "<div class='entry'><h1>".$postInfo['article_title']."</h1>
      <p>".$postInfo['article_content']."</p>
      </div>"
```

manipulating string in PHP

Comment: Is it differ from my answer?

Comment: we are answer in the same time rake,,

Comment: @RakeshSharma, when you're answering simple questions, you should expect duplicate answers.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie on the stack there is not any simple question everyone asks when they stuck sure you do same :)

Comment: yeah,  maybe, are you think, i was copy your code ?

Comment: @RakeshSharma, I'm talking about you insinuating to all the other answerers that they copied your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `variable substitution` :

```
echo "<div class='entry'><h1>".$postInfo['article_title']."</h1>
      <p>".$postInfo['article_content']."</p>
      </div>";
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wanted is just taking variable not its array key, you need to concentrate php variable. You can do it in the following ways

```
  echo "<div class='entry'><h1>".$postInfo['article_title']."</h1>
          <p>".$postInfo['article_content']."</p>
          </div>";
```

AND

```
echo "<div class='entry'><h1>{$postInfo['article_title']}</h1>
      <p>{$postInfo['article_content']}</p>
      </div>";
```

Hope this helps you